# Specifying the Encoding format on XMLDoc

Tags: c#, xml

I have a System.Xml.XmlDocument object and I want to change the xml Encoding from UT16 to UTF8. How do I do it?

Comment: The question makes no sense.  UTF-8 is the default.  Are you actually trying to load a .xml and convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlDocument uses it's own (DOM-based) internal representation of the XML; the encoding only comes into play when the XML is writen to and stored as text somewhere.  You can use the [XmlDocument.WriteTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.writeto.aspx) method and provide an `XmlWriter` configured using an `XmlWriterSettings` passed in to `XmlWriter.Create`.  There is an [XmlWriterSettings.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.encoding.aspx) property where you can specify UTF8.

For example:

```
XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filename, xmlWriterSettings))
{
    XmlDocument.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
}
```